# Change executable text file default behaviour to "execute"

Tags: nautilus, 22.04

I have a text file that has the execute permission, but when I click on it, it opens in a text editor instead of being executed.

When I put in on the desktop and double click it, it executes properly, but not from the file explorer.

I have found several answers that describe how to change this behaviour but only in previous versions of Ubuntu. In 22.04, I don't see an option to set executable text files to "Run executable text files when they are opened"

I have looked in the Preferences of the file explorer [image: Preference]

and in dconf-editor settings for nautilus [image: dconf-editor]

but I don't see the option.

Where is this setting available in Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: It's just how new versions of Nautilus behave. I don't think you can run executable scripts from Nautilus anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, as pointed by @raj, it seems like there is no way to have that behaviour by default anymore.

It is now possible to explicitly run a text file as a script through right click > Run as a program.

Although it is not the answer I was looking for, it seems to be the closest thing to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

on GNOME 3.38 [I found an option on dconf-editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nybTa.png)  that let you choose the behavior of text file execution on nautilus,
**org-> gnome -> nautilus -> preferences -> executable-text-activation**

1. execute as a program [launch]
2. open as a text file [display]
3. ask "ask every time either launch or display"

so in your case if you want to execute text files on nautilus you would choose "launch" option.

if no option found in dconf-editor, you can run this command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation <option>
```

put either 'launch', 'ask', 'display' in place of , here is also a script you can use for the same command

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the value is provided as an argument
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "Please provide a value as the first argument."
  echo "Possible values: 'launch', 'ask', 'display'"
  exit 1
fi

# Set the executable-text-activation preference
# Possible values: 'launch', 'ask', 'display'
value="$1"
gsettings set org.gnome.nautilus.preferences executable-text-activation "$value"

echo "Executable text activation set to: $value"
```

first make the script executable `chmod +x <scriptName>.sh` then run it `./<scriptName>.sh <option>`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).